# Recreating Xen configuration from existing domain

Tags: configuration, xen, rhel5

I have a bunch of Xen DomUs running on Xen 3.3.2 on RHEL5.4. I've setup those VMs as a complete Xen rookie and now I notice that using virt-manager might not have been the best idea, since I don't have any python-based configuration files at all, only `config.sxp` file for each domain in `/var/lib/xend/domains`. Apparently, it's a good idea to have them though, so my question is: how can I recover from my newbie mistakes and re-create those configuration files without starting from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on RHEL5, then using virt-manager, virsh, and other [libvirt](http://libvirt.org/)-related tools is indeed the correct approach.  You do not want to be editting those Xen files in /var/lib/xend/domains; let Xen manage things on its own.

libvirt manages a configuration database somewhere in /var for you, and using `virsh edit <vm name>` you can modify the virtual machine configuration.

Another upside to this approach is the fact that if you switch virtualization platforms (for instance to KVM when RHEL6 is released), your workflow with virt-manager will not be affected.

Comment: Thanks, `virsh edit` seems to work like I wished! Now I have to find those xenpv drivers for the updated kernel ;)